# Class referenced in the manifest, androidx.core.content.FileProvider, was not found in the project or the libraries

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to install a package from pub.dev which requires adding  to android manifest
until I got the error above;

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

        package="com.abc.def">
        <provider
```

The issue is from the line below

```
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" //<<<==========================

            android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.shekarmudaliyar.social_share"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your gradle like

kotlin_version = 1.5.0

com.android.tools.build:gradle version

Hope, the problem will be solved.